# How get progress percentage in sending request? axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm currently creating React app now in which it should have progress percentage while sending the request.

I don't understand, it always logs directly one message which is *100%* in my console even the request has not-yet-completed/pending.

Code in my *axios*:

```
onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
    let percent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
    console.log(`percentage => ${percentage}`);
},
```

In my *console*:
[image]

I expect to have like these output like in this [youtube-tutorial](https://youtu.be/Ti8QNiRRzOA?t=377)

[image]

Comment: That Youtube video made it clear. Thanks!